# Incorrect location detection

Tags: intel

How do I fix the location detection error ?

Here is the city of Simferopol, it is located in the Russian Federation:

> [image]

Which results in a domain error.

Any ideas ?

I have one, but I think that not everyone will like it.

Comment: Bug reported at https://pad.lv/1920987 .

Comment: Thanks. What should I do with it now, what should I click on there ?

Comment: Click Moscow, as it is GMT+3 too.

Comment: Understood, thank you. And on the link where the error report is, I don't need to click anything ?

Comment: You can click *Does this bug affect you?* → *Yes, it affects me*.

Answer (score 0):

Public bug reported at https://pad.lv/1920987 .

Temporary in GNOME Control Center you can select **Moscow**, as it is GMT+3 too.

On the bug report - click *Does this bug affect you?* → *Yes, it affects me* to inform the launchpad that you are affected by this bug.